# CPT without slug after domain mapping

Tags: custom-post-types, domain-mapping

I made a custom solution where two domains are mapped on single site, part of the pages are mapped to one domain and part to another. I used "Multidomain mapping on single site" plugin for that.

This is operational now for two years and works well. It was the best solution for this particular customer, since it works best for them to have all media resources and other admin custom parts on one place, not on two separate wp instances/multidomain.

Now, they want to separate pages on one domain into separate area in admin. I made a custom post type for that and moved related pages to that cpt, but I now have a problem since redirection does not work correctly anymore. Although everything is set up well for redirection in plugin, redirection does not work well (cpt slug stays).
Example:

rule in plugin
firstdomain/slug => seconddomain

It redirects in an (incorrect) way:

firstdomain/slug => seconddomain/slug

I would like to have this redirected without slug. It seems that slug is added after redirection. Now I am studying rewrite api and plugin to see how I can fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you have used a plugin to achieve all this configuration, my first thought in mind was to check with the plugin developer, since he is deep in his own code and could propably give you the best estimation of the situation and what you can do. Also, the customer thinks that everything is fine with his needs and coming features. In fact you are going down the customization rabbit-whole, which will only lead deeper into more custom problems. On the mid-term, I'd try to s twitch to a self-written plugin solution, which you have full control over and can be treated independendly from the rest.

Comment: I already solved the problem, I will paste solution below

Comment: I also thought about self-written plugin, but upon inspecting this plugin code, I figured out that it is not so easy, one must account on many things. Rewriting in URL, rewriting links in page content, rewriting links in menus, rewriting in admin part, etc. There are more details into that, and I would not go into presenting those details here, in five words - it is not so easy.

Comment: oh, yes, and to facilitate domain remapping, plugin changes $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and there are differences in treating Apache and NGINX, so this is really no joke to make yourself

Answer (score 1):

The solution was actually quite lightweight. I found it by inspecting the plugin code. Luckily, plugin developer put a lot of filters and actions to extend and modify plugin functioning, so solution is also futureproof. The slug used for custom post type here is `uciliste`.

Somewhere in PHP which loads before page (e.g. functions.php) this should be put:

```
// map all uciliste pages through falke plugin
add_filter( 'falke_mdmf_request_uri', function($newRequestURI) {
    return  $newRequestURI . ($newRequestURI === '/uciliste/' ? 'uciliste/' : '');
});
```

This filter prevents double slug appearing in url, like this: https://seconddomain/uciliste/uciliste (the first comes from cpt slug, second from remapping)

Further, in plugins settings the slug `/uciliste` should be mapped to second domain, and that's it.